# my mac keep running every 53mins after sleep/lid

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra

This is what in my Istatus Menu
[As picture shows, my mac is running every 53 min when i'm sleeping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKgl6.png)

```
pmset -g assertions
2018-04-18 11:50:48 -0400
Assertion status system-wide:
BackgroundTask                 1
ApplePushServiceTask           0
UserIsActive                   1
PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
PreventSystemSleep             0
ExternalMedia                  0
PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
pid 3151(mds): [0x00000bc7000b840a] 00:06:56 BackgroundTask named: 
"com.apple.metadata.mds.power"
pid 104(hidd): [0x00000b49000983d7] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: 
"com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294968218.3"
Timeout will fire in 600 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler

pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
standbydelay         10800
standby              1
womp                 0
halfdim              1
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
powernap             0
gpuswitch            2
networkoversleep     0
disksleep            10
sleep                10 (sleep prevented by mds, coreaudiod)
autopoweroffdelay    28800
hibernatemode        3
autopoweroff         0
ttyskeepawake        1
displaysleep         10
tcpkeepalive         1
acwake               0
lidwake              1
```

This is the sleep settings on my macbook pro, I experimented that if I turn off the wifi and my mac will stop running every 53 mins after lid. However, it will be so annoying to turn off wifi everytime I lid the mac.I really want to know what is running every 53 mins...

I checked the system log and it shows:

```
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP syslogd[43]: ASL Sender Statistics
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000005.BetterTouchTool[2856]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by BTTRelaunch[2860]
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP systemstats[54]: assertion failed: 17E199: systemstats + 914800 [D1E75C38-62CE-3D77-9ED3-5F6D38EF0676]: 0x40
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Apr 18 08:14:13 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.796 [DFR] ERR [_DFRDisplayUsbSendComplete] writePipeAsync failed 0xe00002ed
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.796 [DFR] ERR [_DFRDisplayUsbRecvComplete] failed 0xe00002ed
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.799 [DFR] [deviceTerminate] 
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.799 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayDeviceRemoved] 
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.799 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayDeviceRemoved_block_invoke] calling client detach callback
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.800 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayClose] 
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.830 [DFR] [deviceMatch] 
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.830 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayDeviceAdded] 
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.831 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayUsbStart] 
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.831 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayOpen] 
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.831 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayOpen] sending GetInfo
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.832 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayHandleVendorPacket] kDFRDisplayCommandGetInfo ready: 0
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.832 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayHandleVendorPacket] calling client attach callback
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.833 [DFR] ERR [_DFRDisplayHandlePacket] error: 0xe00002c7
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.834 [DFR] ERR [_DFRDisplayHandlePacket] error: 0xe00002c7
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP TouchBarServer[232]: 27814.837 [DFR] ERR [_DFRDisplayHandlePacket] error: 0xe00002c7
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.hegenberg.BTTRelaunch.27164[2860]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15 sent by BetterTouchTool[2962]
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP systemstats[54]: assertion failed: 17E199: systemstats + 914800 [D1E75C38-62CE-3D77-9ED3-5F6D38EF0676]: 0x40
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.2957): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/IDETouchBarSimulatorService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
Apr 18 08:14:13 YaochengdeMBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.2957): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/RootDebuggingXPCService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
Apr 18 08:14:14 YaochengdeMBP BetterTouchTool[2962]: assertion failed: 17E199: libxpc.dylib + 75489 [25DB244E-217D-3CE0-A8F2-0C4255783B42]: 0x89
```

It seems my computer waking up by touchbar or something and printed my UI, is that my computer got hacked?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) There's quite a few possibilities to explain this, but the first thing you really should do is reboot your Mac and test to see if this happens without other software running (e.g. I see you had Xcode and the Simulator running). If your Mac still does this, then try booting into Safe Mode and testing again. To boot into Safe Mode, shutdown your Mac and power it up again and immediately hold and keep the Shift key down until you see the login window. Then login and test again.

Comment: @Monomeeth I reinstalled system and problem gone. Ty very much